# how to show current date on month calender from menu item of other form using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a windows app. There is a menubar on main interface
and on the main interface there is a panel. On click event of "View
Calender" there is another form on the panel. On that form there is
a monthcalender. I want to show current date bolded on click event of
"Jump to Today" menu item. Please help me.

This code is on click event of "View Calender" button, which load the form
on panel of main interface.

```
Calender obj = new Calender();
obj.TopLevel = false;

  if (panel2.Controls.Count > 0)
      {
          panel2.Controls.Clear();
          panel2.Controls.Add(obj);
          obj.TopLevel = false;
          obj.Show();
      }
 else
      {
           obj.TopLevel = false;
           panel2.Controls.Add(obj);
           obj.Show();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
  Calender obj = new Calender();
  obj.TopLevel = false;

  if (panel2.Controls.Count > 0)
  {
      panel2.Controls.Clear();
      panel2.Controls.Add(obj);
      obj.TopLevel = false;
      obj.Show();
  }
  else
  {
       obj.TopLevel = false;
       panel2.Controls.Add(obj);
       obj.Show();
  }
  panel2.Controls.add(new Label{
       Text = DateTime.Now
  });
```

You will need to add a click event to the label, as well as set the font however you like it.

Comment: no dear, there is calender control on other form. On that control current date should be bolded on click event of menu item 'jump to today'.